# Drupal 7 with Display Suite and Apache SOLR search environments

Tags: 7, search, display-suite

I have the magnificent Display Suite working for search results but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use it to modify a search environment defined on admin/config/search/apachesolr/search-pages.  Please can someone explain how do I use DS to change the display?

---

Outstanding.  After a weekend of searching it turns out this is a known bug (http://drupal.org/node/1166114) which may be fixed in Drupal 8.

Does anyone know the best method for encouraging it to be fixed quickly in D7?  I'd be prepared to contribute to a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

The second branch of Display Suite has full support for Apache Solr pages, it basically takes it over by default. This hasn't been committed to the first branch as it involves to much changes.

The second branch doesn't have much changes - you might get some notices first, but re-saving the Display configuration solves those.

The biggest change is the default template files which are a little different because the 'Hide empty regions' option has been removed. The logic for collapsing regions is now in the template file itself. That's why we now ship with a 2 column and 2 column fluid template for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the active and default search modules in admin/config/search/settings to "Search Display".

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the only active search module is "search display" and the only default search module is "search display".  Any other ideas, please?

Comment: May be I have this the wrong way around - may be the problem is knowing what to modify for the results produced by the search pages?  "Search results" (as opposed to teaser etc) works for the regular search.  Is it different for searches defined on admin/config/search/apachesolr/search-pages?